# How to add break tags after inserting a paragraph into html using javascript's createElement

Tags: javascript, html

I've successfully inserted a paragraph element into html page using javascript but the 2nd consecutive paragraph comes side by side and I wish to add a break tag to print them in another line, how do I do that?
Here is a screenshot of my output:

[image: output]

Here is my javascript code:

```
function newtask(){
let ask = prompt("Enter the description of task");
const para = document.createElement("p");
const Textnode = document.createTextNode(ask);
para.appendChild(Textnode);
let text= document.getElementById("new")
text.appendChild(Textnode);
```

}

Here is the relevant html

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<h1>To do List</h1> 
<button onclick="newtask()">New Task</button>

<div id="new">
   <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: change the `text.appendChild(Textnode)` to `text.appendChild(para)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were appending `Textnode` to your parent element, not your new `<p>` element. Here's a quick rewrite that should give you your desired results.

Firstly, create the new `<p>` element, then modify its `innerText` property. After that, just append your new `<p>`.

```js
function newtask() {
  const text = document.getElementById("new");
  const ask = prompt("Enter the description of task");
  const para = document.createElement("p");
  para.innerText = ask;
  text.appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: @CharizardLizard You're most welcome! If that solved it for you, please mark my question as correct so your question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `p` inside a `div` and add a `display: flex` configuration.

```
const paraDiv = document.createElement("div");
// Add your style configuration to your paraDiv
function newtask(){
    let ask = prompt("Enter the description of task");
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    paraDiv.appendChild(para)
    const Textnode = document.createTextNode(ask);
    para.appendChild(Textnode);
    let text= document.getElementById("new")
    text.appendChild(Textnode);
}
```